# How to register and use Azure in China from outside China?

Tags: web-hosting, azure, cloud, international

I need to host a CMS website for an international company looking to expand into China.

The company has a registered entity in China, but we as the developer and support team responsible for provisioning and hosting the site, do not.

Our favored approach would be to host with Azure partners  azure.cn but there seems to be no registration or contact process for customers outside of China. Registration requires a Chinese phone number for verification.

Can anyone explain the registration process?

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered duplicate and recommendations on services, products and resources are off-topic too.

Comment: Hi simon, this is a question asking how to register and use a service, I've made some edits to make it clear. Please could you reopen?

Comment: Done... you will need to use your customers telephone number, or obtain a Chinese number using VoIP. Or, you do the sensible thing which everyone else does, is use the standard Azure in your country, because it sounds like you are the customer, not your client, and launch the instance within that region (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/regions/). Azure will class you as the customer, not your client. If they register it, and you administrate it, then they are the customer.